# Oracle SQL Order By with XML and Union ALL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I wrote a select statement like this:

```
Select 
 xmlagg(xmlelement( "Species", 
                  xmlelement("Type",Type),
                  xmlelement("Name",Name),
                  xmlforest(case when Tail is not null then Tail else null end "Trait")))
From Table_Animals
Order By Name;
```

This is my input

[image]

The query runs fine, but when I added an UNION ALL like so:

```
 Select 
 xmlagg(xmlelement( "Species", 
                  xmlelement("Type",Type),
                  xmlelement("Name",Name),
                  xmlforest(case when Tail is not null then Tail else null  end "Trait")))
 From Table_Animals

UNION ALL 

 Select 
 xmlagg(xmlelement( "Species", 
                  xmlelement("Type",Type),
                  xmlelement("Name",Name),
                  xmlforest(case when Teeth is not null then Teeth else null end "Trait")))
 From Table_Animals
 Where Prey is not null
 Order By Name;
```

I got the error : `ORA-00904: "Name": invalid identifier`

How do I use Order By correctly in the above example?

My desired output is:

```
    <Species>
    <Type>Bird<Type>
    <Name>Eagle<Name>
    <Species>
    <Species>
    <Type>Mammal<Type>
    <Name>Fox<Name>
    <Trait>Sharp<Trait>
    <Species>
    <Species>
    <Type>Plant<Type>
    <Name>Lettuce<Name>
    <Species>
    <Species>
    <Type>Mammal<Type>
    <Name>Rabbit<Name>
    <Trait>Short<Trait>
    <Species>
    <Species>
    <Type>Mammal<Type>
    <Name>Rabbit<Name>
    <Trait>Dull<Trait>
    <Species>  
    <Species>
    <Type>Amphibian<Type>
    <Name>Snake<Name>
    <Trait>Long<Trait>
    <Species>
    <Species>
    <Type>Amphibian<Type>
    <Name>Snake<Name>
    <Trait>Sharp<Trait>
    <Species>
```

Notice that Snake and Rabbit shows up twice in the output

Comment: what are you trying to do? Order the items within the xml document? Please edit your question to include some sample input data, along with the output you're trying to get.

Comment: I am trying to grab data and spool it out to an XML document in an order. I've edited my question to include some sample input and output data

Comment: Interesting thing is how the first query (without UNION) works at all. Adding the `name` as a column in the query gives `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`. But somehow manages Oracle to order the single row on a non existing column. This `select count(*) from Table_Animals order by name;`seems to be a **valid statement**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the result of [XMLAgg](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm) using the `order_by_clause` of XMLAgg.

In the first step perform a simple `UNION ALL`(without XML) to duplicate the data as required.

Finalyy use the  `order_by_clause` of XMLAgg

example data

```
create table Table_Animals as
select 'T1' type, 'dog' name, 'tai1' tail, 'Y' prey, 'tee1' teeth from dual union all
select 'T1' type, 'elephant' name, 'tai2' tail, 'Y' prey, 'tee2' teeth from dual union all
select 'T2' type, 'cat' name, 'tai3' tail, null prey, 'tee3' teeth from dual;
```

The query

```
with ua as (
select TYPE, NAME, TAIL, PREY, TEETH, Tail as trait from Table_Animals union all
select TYPE, NAME, TAIL, PREY, TEETH, Teeth  as trait from Table_Animals where Prey is not null)
Select 
 xmlagg(xmlelement( "Animal", 
                  xmlelement("Type",Type),
                  xmlelement("Name",Name),
                  xmlelement("Trait",Trait)) order by name) xml_col
From ua
;
```

*note the definition of the column `trait` in teh subquery.
*note the **order by name** near the `xml_col`*

gives

```
<Animal>
  <Type>T2
  </Type>
  <Name>cat
  </Name>
  <Trait>tai3
  </Trait>
</Animal>
<Animal>
  <Type>T1
  </Type>
  <Name>dog
  </Name>
  <Trait>tai1
  </Trait>
</Animal>
<Animal>
  <Type>T1
  </Type>
  <Name>dog
  </Name>
  <Trait>tee1
  </Trait>
</Animal>
<Animal>
  <Type>T1
  </Type>
  <Name>elephant
  </Name>
  <Trait>tai2
  </Trait>
</Animal>
<Animal>
  <Type>T1
  </Type>
  <Name>elephant
  </Name>
  <Trait>tee2
  </Trait>
</Animal>
```

Comment: I've edited my question per @boneist's request. The reason why I used Union All is because I need some items to be in the output twice. If I follow your example using Union all, I would have the top part of my list ordered by name followed by the bottom part ordered by name. I'm trying to figure out a way to order the whole list by name